# How to manage users in the ASP.NET Membership DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership

I am using ASP.NET Membership (createUserWizard) signUp for my website.and now I want to manage the Users that registered by createuserwizard that mean I wanna to edit roles and delete users from all asp.net tables.
for this purpose I have a gridview that is connected to a sqlDatasourse. I wrote the connection string code manually in sqldatasourse So I can't use Advanced (Delete,Update,Insert) in datasourse. How can I do this work by my own cod?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="manage-users.aspx.cs" Inherits="manage_users" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="نام کاربری" 
            SortExpression="UserName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastActivityDate" HeaderText="تاریخ آخرین فعالیت " 
            SortExpression="LastActivityDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="ایمیل " SortExpression="Email" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsApproved" HeaderText="فعال" 
            SortExpression="IsApproved" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsLockedOut" HeaderText="مسدود" 
            SortExpression="IsLockedOut" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastLockoutDate" HeaderText="تاریخ آخرین مسدودیت" 
            SortExpression="LastLockoutDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RoleName" HeaderText="نقش کاربری" 
            SortExpression="RoleName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:akhbarrConnectionString %>"  
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SabteAKhabar.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT aspnet_Users.UserName, aspnet_Users.LastActivityDate, aspnet_Membership.Email, aspnet_Membership.IsApproved, aspnet_Membership.IsLockedOut, aspnet_Membership.LastLockoutDate, aspnet_Roles.RoleName FROM aspnet_Users INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId INNER JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles ON aspnet_UsersInRoles.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId INNER JOIN aspnet_Roles ON aspnet_Roles.RoleId = aspnet_UsersInRoles.RoleId"></asp:SqlDataSource>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: It's hard for me to figure out what you're asking. Are you trying to use the more advanced features of the GridView and can't? What specific problem do you have if you try to change the DataSource to something like an ObjectDataSource and do it that way?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker actually I want to edit user's Data that is saved in aspnetDB, but I don't know how can I do this

Comment: Get thee to SQL Server Management Studio!